# array of phone numbers checking using nspredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I've an array of phone numbers from that i need to check a particular(given) phone number is contain in that array or not.So how can i do that by using NSPredicate.(NB currently i am using array contains object method.in my problem i need a solution using predicate). So If anyone know this please help me

```
 NSString *p = allUsers.phoneNumber;
            NSString *p1 = [p stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
            NSString *p2 = [p1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
            NSString *p3 = [p2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
            NSString *p4 = [p3 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
            NSString *p5 = [p4 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];
            NSString *p6 = [p5 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"*" withString:@""];
            NSString *p7 = [p6 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];


 if ([arrayAllPhoneNumbers containsObject:p7])
            {
                allUsers.isPhoneUser = YES;

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// For number kind of values:
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF = %@", value];
NSArray *results = [array_to_search filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

// For string kind of values:
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", value];
NSArray *results = [array_to_search filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

// For any object kind of value (yes, you can search objects also):
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", value];
NSArray *results = [array_to_search filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: @abymathew : just remember to do [result objectAtIndex:0] to get the actual result.

Comment: thanks both of u for great answers...my exact problem is this arrayallphonenumber[@12345,@5678], then in my p7 value is 345 so i need to take 12345 value from arrayallphonenumbers so how can i get this

Comment: ok guys thanks for your valueble answers...i got my solution...from your answers...

Comment: @abymathew, please accept this as an answer, so if other people try to face the smae issue then this will helpful to them.

Answer (score 1):

One good solution is there in-spite of using NSPredicate you can try with `NSDatDetector`
Please try below:-

```
NSString *p = @"8147744507";
NSError *error = NULL;
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink|NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber
                                                           error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:p
                                     options:0
                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, [p length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches)
{
    if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber)
    {
        NSString *phoneNumber = [match phoneNumber];
        NSLog(@"phone no valid=%@",phoneNumber);
    }
}
```